# Google Drive API: Error on OAuth2 token

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-api-php-client

I would like to create a webapp that use Google Drive as a storage and I'm playing with the Google API but I have a problem with the authentication.
I have choose the Service account as a authentication method but when I try to run the script I got this error:

> An error occurred: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
>   "error" : "invalid_grant" }'Array ( )

The code is the following:

```
<?php
require_once 'api/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'api/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once "api/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";
session_start();

$service = buildService();

$fileList = retrieveAllFiles($service);
print_r($fileList);

/**
 * Build and returns a Drive service object authorized with the service accounts.
 *
 * @return Google_DriveService service object.
 */
function buildService($userEmail) {

  $DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxxapps.googleusercontent.com';
  $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'xxx-privatekey.p12';

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $auth->prn = $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL;

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}


/**
 * Retrieve a list of File resources.
 *
 * @param Google_DriveService $service Drive API service instance.
 * @return Array List of Google_DriveFile resources.
 */
function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: I think this is easier than using Google Drive -> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil but that's just my opinion. I have no time to waste on random errors that pop out of nowhere.

Comment: FWIW I'm here because a WordPress plugin I was using (Google Drive integration) has the same error. Fortunately I can take my business elsewhere. (Google has a brand/marketing problem here.) This is the problem with proprietary technology, you get locked in and then you have unique problems and become somebody's dog.

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to [delegate domain-wide authority to your service account's client ID](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)?

Comment: follow the steps in the link above to grant your client id access to the Google Drive scopes you wish to use.

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions. They don't specify what's granting what to what, it's a generic solution to a generic problem. BTW the instructions need updating because some of the wording has changed.

Comment: you are granting the app access to the given scopes for all users in your domain.

Comment: OK Jay but that's not what the instructions say.  "For example if you need domain-wide access to the Google Drive API and the Google Calendar API enter: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"

Comment: It's not clear to me what's not clear to you here. Can you clarify what you're trying to do with service accounts? It might be worth starting a new SO question with the specifics of your use case...